# Keep getting 404 Error for static JSON with axios (vue cli)

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, command-line-interface, http-status-code-404

I started a simple Vue project and faced the first problems with static data.
I have a json file `tours.json` which keeps getting a 404 Error through axios `GET` request.

```
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    const tours = 'http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json';
    export default {
        name: "TourInformations",
        data() {
            return {
                tourInformations: ''
            };
        },
        methods: {},
        created() {
            axios.get(tours).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))

        }  
    };
    </script>
```

First things I tried were changing the path to my json file. Didn't help.
I tried to use relative paths, to use `localhost:8080` with and without `http://` respecitve `https://`.

The console keeps saying:

`GET http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json 404 (Not Found)`

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:59)
```

Thanks for every help!

Edit: What's weird is that I get a response when I use an external API like jsonplaceholder or others with the same code. Why is this?
Changing my address to https:// shows a CORS error. I don't think I'm with CORS on a better way. I'm confused. Especially as a beginner I cannot understand why a simple path to a local JSON file doesn't work, but a path to a secure external API does.

Edit2: Putting my `/server/tours.json` into the `public` folder works for now. The data is shown in the `console`. 
This is now where my `json` file is stored: `'http://localhost:8080/public/server/tours.json`. 
All fine here.

But when I move my `json` file into every other folder and changing my route accordingly. It doesn't matter how I try to adapt my route to the new place of my `json` file, it keeps showing 404 error.
For example: 
If I move `/server/tours.json` into my `src` directory, change my axios path **from** `http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json` **to** `http://localhost:8080/src/server/tours.json` it shows `404 (GET http://localhost:8080/src/server/tours.json 404 (Not Found)`). The route to my file should be correct like this.
A 404 appears also with a relative path like `../server/tours.json`. (My axios code from above is placed in on of my components where I am changing my path depending of the location of my `json`.

Here's my (simplified) file structure:

```
    root
    ├── public
    ├────── favicon.ico
    ├────── index.html
    ├────── server
    ├──────────tours.json
    ├── src
    ├────── assets
    ├────── components
    ├───────── Tours.vue ###My axios code in here
    ├──────────── ...
    ├────── App.vue
    ├────── main.js
    ...
```

The route `http://localhost:8080/public/server/tours.json` with the file structure above works. Okay.

And here is the file structure and route which shows a `404 Error`.
`http://localhost:8080/src/server/tours.json`

```
    root
    ├── public
    ├────── favicon.ico
    ├────── index.html
    ├── src
    ├───────server
    ├──────────tours.json
    ├────── assets
    ├────── components
    ├───────── Tours.vue ###My axios code in here
    ├──────────── ...
    ├────── App.vue
    ├────── main.js
    ...
```

So the `json` in `public` works, an external API works to. The axios snippet is correct. It's about the ropute right? I tried (feels like) every possible route which could cause the issue. I'm confused.

What I miss? This topic should be much much shorter. So, there's something I miss here. Otherwise I cannot explain why something simple like a proper file route seems to be so confusing.

It's obviously not the route which is wrong. Even if I move my `json` to my `root` and change my path into `http://localhost:8080/tours.json` it shows a `404`.

Comment: Is `localhost:8080` the address of your Vue development server or is it some other server? Where, relative to your Vue files, have you put the file `tours.json` on your file-system? What happens if you just open the URL directly in a web browser, just typing the URL directly into the address bar? Until you can get that working there's no way you'll be able to write suitable code to retrieve it from the UI. On the face of it the problem just appears to be that there's a mismatch between the location of the file on your file-system and the URL you're using to access it.

Comment: It's the address of my Vue development server.
My `tours.json` is outside of the `src` in a seperate `server` folder. 
If I enter the URL into my browser, it brings me to my Vue app like normal.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is simply that you've put the file in the wrong place on your file-system.

Assuming you're using Vue CLI and you want the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json
```

then you should place the file at the path:

```
project-root/public/server/tours.json
```

For reference, `index.html` will typically be at the path:

```
project-root/public/index.html
```

Official documentation:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

There are other ways to achieve a similar effect using custom configuration of the server but dropping static assets into the `public` folder should work out-of-the-box.

**Update:**

Based on your comments and the updated question I'm going to try to explain further.

Firstly, completely ignore the axios part here. As you've suggested in the question that isn't the problem. You can replicate exactly the same behaviour by typing these URLs directly into your browser address bar, you'll get a 404 just the same as you are with axios.

The underlying problem here seems to be that you believe that there's a direct correspondence between the file structure within your project's root folder and the 'routes', or URL paths. This is not the case. They are two separate things.

Let's consider for a moment what happens when you make a request to a web server. Not necessarily the Vue development server, any web server.

When you make a request to a web server it is entirely at that server's discretion to decide what to send back. So a request to `http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json` involves contacting the server at `localhost:8080` and asking it for `server/tours.json`.

On the face of it that might appear to be asking for the *file* `tours.json` from the folder `server`. However, that is not necessarily the case. It is up to the server to decide what `server/tours.json` means and what the response should be. Not only does the response not have to the contents of a file but it doesn't even have to be static. The server could generate a response on-the-fly, maybe based on the result of a database query.

It is really important to understand this. Sending a request of `http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json` does not *necessarily* mean *'give me the file `tours.json` from the folder `server`'*. It is entirely at the server's discretion to decide what to return.

Now, it is common for a web server to have to handle static assets. The easiest way to store such assets is as files. Rather than configuring individual mappings between URL paths and file-system paths it is generally easier to organise the files in a folder structure that maps conveniently onto the URL paths. Typically the web server would be configured to treat a particular folder as the 'root' for static assets and then all the folders/files within that root would be served up using matching URL paths.

In general, the exact mechanism for configuring this would depend on which web server you're using. Of course we're specifically interested in the Vue development server, so let's get back to considering that particular server.

There is a lot of stuff going on behind the scenes with the Vue development server. It is not simply serving up files from the file-system.

The contents of the `src` folder require a build. They won't be served up as-is to the browser. The server won't treat them as static assets. If you try to access `http://localhost:8080/src/App.vue` you'll find you get a 404 response. That is to be expected.

Instead the server will go through the contents of the `src` folder and generate the 'files' that it needs. For example it'll pull apart all the `.js` and `.vue` files and use them to create one big `app.js` containing everything. If you look in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools you should see the 'file' `app.js` being loaded. But this 'file' doesn't actually exist, it is generated dynamically based on the contents of the files in the `src` folder.

However, it is common for a Vue project to need some static assets. A default CLI project will have an `index.html` and `favicon.ico`. These don't need to be generated dynamically so it is convenient just to store them as files on the file-system. The Vue server has a special folder, called `public`, for holding such files. As discussed earlier, any folders/files within that folder will be mapped directly onto equivalent URL paths (what the question calls *routes*). The folder `public` is treated as the root folder for these mappings. So a file located on the file-system at `project-root/public/server/tours.json` will be mapped onto the URL path `server/tours.json`, in full `http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json`. The 'route' is relative to the `public` folder, not relative to the project's root folder.

While that covers the most important details there are a couple of other things I would note for the sake of completeness.

Firstly, strictly speaking the contents of the `public` folder are not all static. For the file `index.html` there's some Webpack magic goes on to inject various things within the page. This is described [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-index-file) but it isn't something worth dwelling on when it comes to understanding how to serve up a simple `.json` file.

Secondly, it is also possible to include static assets within the `src` folder, but only in specific cases. For example, the default Vue CLI project creates a file at `src/assets/logo.png`. However, there is yet more Webpack magic going on here. Once this has been through the build it will have a URL something like `http://localhost:8080/img/logo.82b9c7a5.png`. Note that this is significantly different from the original path on the file-system. Webpack will trawl through your `.js` and `.vue` files and try to update any relative paths that access `src/assets/logo.png` to point them at the generated path instead. I'm not going to go into detail about precisely how that works here as I don't think it is relevant to the original question. Just be aware that there are limits on when it will work, it isn't actually magic.

There is a somewhat equivalent way of accessing a `.json` file in the `src` folder but it doesn't generate a 'route' at all. If you place a `.json` file somewhere within your `src` folder then you can import it using `import` just like you would a `.js` or `.vue` file:

```js
import tours from '../server/tours.json'
```

It is important to appreciate that this is not making a separate AJAX request to the server to load the file. Instead this is telling Webpack to bundle the contents of `tours.json` into `app.js` during the build. No 'route' will be created for `tours.json` if you include it this way.

I'll now go through a couple of the specific remarks in the question to try to clarify where misunderstandings appear to be lurking.

> Putting my `/server/tours.json` into the `public` folder works for now. The data is shown in the `console`. This is now where my json file is stored: `http://localhost:8080/public/server/tours.json`. All fine here.

If you put the file at `public/server/tours.json` on your file-system then it will be mapped to a URL of `http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json`. The `public` will be dropped as it is considered to be the root when it comes to serving up static files.

In the quote above you have claimed that the file is stored at `http://localhost:8080/public/server/tours.json`. I don't believe that is correct. As you noted previously in the comments the URL path will not contain the `/public` part.

You should be able to test URL paths by typing them directly into your browser's address bar.

If you need to clarify what URL axios is calling then take a look in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. That will show you the full URL that it requested.

> But when I move my `json` file into every other folder and changing my route accordingly. It doesn't matter how I try to adapt my route to the new place of my `json` file, it keeps showing 404 error.

The Vue server does not create routes for all files. It only creates routes for files inside the `public` folder. So if you put your file somewhere outside the `public` folder there won't be a corresponding route. No amount of tweaking the URL will help, the route does not exist.

> For example: If I move `/server/tours.json` into my `src` directory, change my axios path **from** `http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json` **to** `http://localhost:8080/src/server/tours.json` it shows `404 (GET http://localhost:8080/src/server/tours.json 404 (Not Found))`. The route to my file should be correct like this.

Afraid not.

Putting it in the `src` folder won't have any effect on the available routes. Only putting it in the `public` folder will cause a route to be created.

You may well have several other files in your `src` folder. None of these files will be mapped directly onto a route either. If you try to access `http://localhost:8080/src/components/Tours.vue` you'll get a 404. Instead these files are bundled up into the Webpack build.

If you have the file `src/server/tours.json` on your file-system then you can access its contents by using `import` within your `.js` and `.vue` files. However, that is all handled by the build process and has nothing to do with creating routes accessible via URLs. That would be a very different process from loading the file via axios.

> It's obviously not the route which is wrong. Even if I move my `json` to my `root` and change my path into `http://localhost:8080/tours.json` it shows a 404.

If you want to access a file using the URL `http://localhost:8080/tours.json` then the correct place to put it on your file-system would be:

```
project-root/public/tours.json
```

Recall that the root for serving static files is the `public` folder. It is not the project's root folder. If you put files outside the `public` folder then the server will usually just ignore them.

Comment: It works with `public`, thanks for that! But why is the `public` ignored by the route? I needed to figure out that, when I added my route like `http://localhost:8080/public/server/tours.json` it **doesnt** work but remove the `public` and make it `http://localhost:8080/server/tours.json` works fine. I couldn't find an explanation in the docs. 
But nevertheless, if I put my `json` file in an other folder it still shows `404`. Even though I checked several times if my route my be wrong. Need to find it out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @DamirLucic You seem to have a false expectation that the server will just serve up all files, no matter where you put them. That isn't how it works. The `public` folder is special. Files in that folder will be served as 'static assets', using a URL equivalent to the file path *within* the `public` folder. If you want to serve up a static file then put it in the `public` folder, simple as that. If you just put it in some random other folder it'll just be ignored.

Comment: I don't expect the server will serve all files no matter where they're placed in. 
I edited my first post and tried to explain precisely why I'm confused.

Comment: @DamirLucic I have added an update to my answer based on your updated question. However, while I have gone into a lot more detail, my answer remains essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation. I read it last week, was quite a lot of informations and read it today again to realized that I misunderstood a lot of things about the whole process behind the code.
I checked the things you mentioned and indeed, you were right. Before your answer I accepted the fact that I can't just pass an URL like I wanted to and continued to work with importing the file "in the normal way" (like you mentioned too)

Answer (score 1):

**I have an alternative solution for this kind of problem in .json file**

the first thing is to

`import projects from '../../static/projects.json'` // import this file in your component

declare an empty array in your data

```
data() {
    return {
        items: []
    }
},
```

and then create a life-cycle method like created or mounted or etc.

```
created () {
        let projectData = projects.projects
        return this.items.push(...projectData)
    }
```

and that's it works just fine without using fetch or axios.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue here is you have the .json file but you need a server to actually send back a response to your GET http request, in this response you will have the json data.

In summary, axios creates an http request, in this case a GET request, and you need another software to respond to this http protocol, this response will contain json data, headers, etc.

I would recommend looking into something like express framework for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. Could you give me an example please?
As I understand it correctly, my axios code should at least give back a response in my console with the correct json data. But the file isn't shown. A external API is shown with the same code snippet.